# How do I display a column from 1 table to another table

Tags: sql, oracle

There are 2 tables, a table named `species` and another table named `planet`.

I want to display the `name, average_height, hair_color, skin_color, homeworld` and `population`. All of the above is in the `species` table except for `population` which is in `planet` table.

What is the query do I have to do to display all of these columns

I am using SQL Developer

Species Table

```
ID
homeworld
name
average_height
skin_color
hair_color
eye_color
language
average_lifespan
classification
```

Planet Table

```
ID
diameter
climate
surface_water
name
rotation_period
terrain
gravity
orbital_period
population
```

Comment: Hint:  `JOIN`.  `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic query would be

```
SELECT s.NAME,
       s.AVERAGE_HEIGHT,
       s.HAIR_COLOR,
       s.SKIN_COLOR,
       s.HOMEWORLD,
       p.POPULATION
  FROM PLANET p
  INNER JOIN SPECIES s
    ON s.HOMEWORLD = p.ID
```

if `SPECIES.HOMEWORLD` is in fact a foreign key to `PLANET.ID`